# PHP update status without submit button using switch box (Ajax)

Tags: php, ajax

I have a list of registered users information. Web admin will activate any eligible user when needed. The users list is in tabulated form with checkbox. I want to enable the user access by ticked the checkbox without submitting the web form. How can that be done?

```
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" <?php if($row['status']=="1") {?> checked="true" <?php } ?>>
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an ajax request. Give the checkbox an id.

```
$('#id-of-checkbox').click(function(){
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $.post('/url-to-ajax-to', {checked: checked}, function(e){
        console.log(e); // do what you need to do afterwards in here
    });
});
```

You might want to pass a row ID too.
Then in your PHP scipt, create an SQL query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE sometable SET checkboxcolumn = :checkval WHERE id = :id";
```

Bind the parameters as normal, execute the query, then send a json response back.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode([
    'whatever' => 'data you might like to return',
    'status' => 'success' //etc
]);
exit;
```